# Problem handling multiple substrings on dynamic string

Tags: java, string, design-patterns

Currently I am having a hard time trying to figure out if there is a better way to refactor the following code.

Given the following:

```
String detail = "POTATORANDOMFOOD";
```

Lets say I want to assign variables with different parts of `detail`, the end result would look something like this.

```java
String title = detail.substring(0, 6); // POTATO
String label = detail.substring(6, 12); // RANDOM
String tag = detail.substring(12, 16); // FOOD
```

Now lets say the string `detail` length constantly changes, sometimes it only contains "POTATORANDOM" and no "FOOD", sometimes it contains even more characters "POTATORANDOMFOODTODAY", so another variable would be used.

```java
String title = detail.substring(0, 6); // POTATO
String label = detail.substring(6, 12); // RANDOM
String tag = detail.substring(12, 16); // FOOD
...
String etc = detail.substring(30, 40); // etc value from detail string
```

The issue with this, is that since the string sometimes is shorter or longer, we would run into the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` which is not good.

So currently I have a naive way to handle this:

```java
if (detail != null || !detail.isEmpty()) {
    if (detail.length() >= 6) {
        title = detail.substring(0, 6);

        if (detail.length() >= 12) {
            label = detail.substring(6, 12);

            if (detail.length() >= 16) {
                tag = detail.substring(12, 16);
                .
                .
                .
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can get really messy, especially if lets say the string were to grow even more.

So my question is, what would be a good design pattern that would fit for this type of problem? I have tried the chain of responsibility design pattern but, the issue with this one is that it only returns a single value, while I am trying to return multiple ones if possible. This way I can assign multiple variables depending on the length of the string.

Any help/hints is greatly appreciated!

**Edited:**

The order and length are always the same. So title will always be first and it will always contain 6 characters. `label` will always be second and it will always contain 6 characters. `tag` will always be third and it will always contain 4 characters, etc.

Comment: Do you know in advance all the occurrences that may be there (for example the fact that the first word, if there, it has length 6 and it's a title)? Also, is there a pattern (cause it seems the first two elements have length 6, the third 4 etc,)?

Comment: What is the purpus of `detail` to be a single `String` without separator ? It is in your control to edit the format of `detail` ?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ The order and length are always the same. So title will always be first and it will always contain 6 characters.

Comment: @FrédéricPerron The string `detail` is given that way and I have no control over how it will initially be received. There are no separators to split the string.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you, I would do the following:

### Define a class to hold a Word definition

```
public class Word {
    private final String name;
    private final int startIndex;
    private final int endIndex; 

    public Word(String name, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        this.name = name;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getStartIndex() { return startIndex; }
    public int getEndIndex() { return endIndex; }
}
```

### Create a static list which holds all the possible words

```
public static final List<Word> WORDS = List.of(
    new Word("title", 0, 6),
    new Word("label", 6, 12),
    new Word("tag", 12, 16),
    ...
);
```

### Create a function that parses the `String detail` by walking this list until when the size of the string is exhausted

... and of course storing the elements into a `Map<String, String>` so that you can access them later.

```
public Map<String, String> parseDetail(String detail) {
    Map<String, String> receivedWords = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //<-- map respecting insertion order
    if (detail.isEmpty()) {
        return receivedWords;
    }
    int parsedLength = 0;        ​
   ​for (Word word : WORDS) {
        ​receivedWords.put(word.getName(), detail.substring(word.getStartIndex(), word.getEndIndex()); //<-- store the current word
        parsedLength += word.getEndIndex() - word.getStartIndex(); //increase the parsedLength by the length of your word
        if (parsedLength >= detail.length()) {
            break; //<-- exit the loop when you're done with the parsing
        } 
   ​}
   return receivedWords;
}
```

---

To sum up:

```
Map<String, String> receivedWords = parseDetail(detail);
receivedWords.forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println("Key: " + k + ", value: " + v);
});
```

Output:

```
Key: title, value: POTATO
Key: label, value: RANDOM
Key: tag, value: FOOD
...
```

**Tip 1:** The input you receive looks pretty weird. I understand that you cannot change it but I would try to negotiate with the caller (if possible) a better way to send you their input (ideally a structured object, if not possible at least a string with some separator so that you can simply split by that character).

**Tip 2:** I have defined the list of words statically in the code. But I would instead define an external file (e.g. a Json file, or an Xml, or even a simple text file) that you parse dynamically to create the list. That will allow someone else to configure this file with the words/start index/end index without you having to do it in the code each time there is a change. ​

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check the length of the total string to see if it has the `RANDOM` and the `FOOD` attributes before using `substring()`

```java
String title = "", label = "", tag = "";

if (detail.length() >= 6)
    title = detail.substring(0, 6);
if (detail.length() >= 12)
    label = detail.substring(6, 12);
if (detail.length() == 16)
    tag = detail.substring(12,16);
```

Comment: This would lead to the same problem as the nested if statements. The only difference is that this is not nested and is checking on all if statements even if the length is really short.

Comment: You absolutely want to avoid `if` statements ? Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a regex aproach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String detail = "POTATORANDOMFOODTODAY";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.{0,6})(.{0,6})(.{0,4})(.{0,5})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(detail);

    m.find();

    String title = m.group(1);
    String label = m.group(2);
    String tag   = m.group(3);
    String day   = m.group(4);

    System.out.println("title: " + title + ", lable: " + label + ", tag: " + tag + ", day: " + day);
}
//output: title: POTATO, lable: RANDOM, tag: FOOD, day: TODAY
```

If you have a lots of groups I would suggest to use named captured groups. The approach above can particularly be difficult to maintain as adding or removing a group in the middle of the regex upsets the previous numbering used via `Matcher#group(int groupNumber)`. Using named capturing groups:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String detail = "POTATORANDOMFOODTODAY";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<title>.{0,6})(?<label>.{0,6})(?<tag>.{0,4})(?<day>.{0,5})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(detail);
    
    m.find();
    
    String title = m.group("title");
    String label = m.group("label");
    String tag   = m.group("tag");
    String day   = m.group("day");

    System.out.println("title: " + title + ", lable: " + label + ", tag: " + tag + ", day: " + day);
}
//output: title: POTATO, lable: RANDOM, tag: FOOD, day: TODAY
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is dynamic then it can essentially contain basically anything and since there can possibly be no whitespace(s) in the string the only way to know what a specific word (substring) might be is to play the string against a 'word list'. You can quickly come to realize how pivotal even a single whitespace (or separator character) can be within a string. Using the [String#substring()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Java-String-substring-Method-example) method is only good if you already know what all the words within the **detail** string happen to be.

The simple solution would be to set acceptable rules as to how a specific string should be received. After all, why would you want to accept a string that contains multiple words without a separator character of some type to begin with. If the string has whitespaces in it, to separate the words contained within that string, a mere:

```
String[] words = string.split("\\s+");
```

line of code would do the trick. Bottom line, get rid of that nonsense of accepting strings containing multiple words with no separation mechanism included, even if that separation mechanism is by making use of the underscore ( **_** ) character (or some other character). Well...if you can.

I suppose sometimes we just can't modify how we're dealt things (something like taxes) and how we receive specific strings is simply out of our control. If this is the case then one way to deal with this dilemma is to work against an established Word-List. This word list can in in the size of a few words to hundreds of thousands of words. The situation you need to deal with will determine the word list size. If small enough the word list can be contained within a String Array or a collection like an ArrayList or List Interface. If really large however then the word list would most likely be contained within a Text file. The word list I most commonly use contains well over 370,000 individual words.

Here is an example of using a small Word-List contained within a List Interface:

```
String detail = "POTATORANDOMFOODTODAY";
        
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "pumpkin", "carrot", "potato", "tomato", "lettus", "radish", "bean",
    "pea", "food", "random", "today", "yesterday", "tomorrow", 
});

// See if the detail string 'contains' any word-list words...
List<String> found = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
    String word = wordList.get(i);
    if (detail.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
        found.add(word.toUpperCase());
    }
}
        
/* Ensure the words within the list are in proper order.
   That is, the same order as they are received within the 
   detail String. This is necessary since words from the 
   word-List can be found anywhere within the detail string.      */
int startIndex = 0;
List<String> foundWords = new ArrayList<>();
String tmpStrg = "";
while (!tmpStrg.equals(detail)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) {
        String word = found.get(i);
        if (detail.indexOf(word) == startIndex) {
            foundWords.add(word);
            startIndex = startIndex + word.length();
            String procStrg = foundWords.toString().replace(", ", "");
            tmpStrg = procStrg.substring(1, procStrg.length() - 1);
        }
    }
}
        
//Format and Display the required data
if (foundWords.isEmpty()) {
    System.err.println("Couldn't find any required words!");
    return; // or whatever...
}
String title = foundWords.get(0);
String label = foundWords.size() > 1 ? foundWords.get(1) : "N/A";
String[] tag = new String[1];
if (foundWords.size() > 2) {
    tag = new String[foundWords.size()-2];
    for (int i = 0; i < foundWords.size() - 2; i++) {
        tag[i] = foundWords.get(i + 2); 
    }
}
else {
    tag[0] = "N/A";
}
        
System.out.println("Title:\t" + title);
System.out.println("Label:\t" + label);
System.out.println("Tags:\t" 
        + Arrays.toString(tag).substring(1, Arrays.toString(tag).length() - 1));
```

When the above code is run the console window would display:

```
Title:  POTATO
Label:  RANDOM
Tags:   FOOD, TODAY
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Stream API and use `filter()` method.
Then you  use `map()` to apply your existing logic, that should do the trick.

Switch-cases could be an alternative but it adds more LoC but reduces the arrow code of all the nested ifs